# Create an sql variable from the query results to use in the same query

Tags: sql

I'd like to do the following query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(violations, CHARINDEX('X', violations, 0), 5) AS 'violations', definition, value, date 
FROM NewViolations WHERE CHARINDEX('X', violations, 0) > 0
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to put `CHARINDEX('X', violations, 0)` into a variable (`VarX`) so that I end up with something like:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(violations, VarX, 5) AS 'violations', definition, value, date
FROM NewViolations WHERE VarX > 0
```

I'm doing this to avoid running CHARINDEX twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select substring(violations, location, 5) as 'violations', definition, value, date
 from (select violations, charindex('x',violations,0) location, definition, value, date
         from NewViolations) a
where a.location>0
```

For the sake of illustration and somewhat less typing, one could (although most would likely frown on it):

```
select substring(violations, location, 5) as 'violations', definition, value, date
 from (select *, charindex('x',violations,0) location
         from NewViolations) a
where a.location>0
```

Comment: Sorry, the example I had wasn't complete. I also need a bunch of columns from the same table other than the substring one.

Comment: Think you should be able to add them to the subselect and then pull them out into the main select.

Comment: Why would your second example be frowned on?

Comment: Well, select * constructs are generally not recommended because they return ALL the data from a table, so its preferable to select only the data that is needed. Reduces network traffic, exposes less information, things of that nature.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+, you could use a CTE:

```
WITH cteCharIndex AS (
    SELECT violations, CHARINDEX('X', violations, 0) AS PosOfX
        FROM NewViolations
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(violations, PosOfX, 5) AS 'violations'
    FROM cteCharIndex
    WHERE PosOfX > 0;
```